# My app is not working in emulator..please help me out

Tags: android

This is the code I would like you to go through.
Please spot my mistakes.
This is a simple code for a calculator app.
I am not sure but the mistake might be in button section of the code.
Would be really grateful if you helped me out in this..
Thanks in advance.

```
package com.iitg.sau_calc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Cal extends Activity {
Button one, two, thr, fou, fiv, six, sev, eig, nin, zer, add, sub, mul, div, clr, equ;
TextView scr;
int ans=0,fans=0,ca=0,cs=0,cm=0,cd=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cal);
    one=(Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
    two=(Button)findViewById(R.id.two);
    thr=(Button)findViewById(R.id.thr);
    fou=(Button)findViewById(R.id.fou);
    fiv=(Button)findViewById(R.id.fiv);
    six=(Button)findViewById(R.id.six);
    sev=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sev);
    eig=(Button)findViewById(R.id.eig);
    nin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nin);
    zer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.zer);
    add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sub);
    mul=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mul);
    div=(Button)findViewById(R.id.div);
    clr=(Button)findViewById(R.id.clr);
    equ=(Button)findViewById(R.id.equ);
    scr=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Screen);


    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ans=ans*10+1;
            scr.setText(ans);
        }
    });

two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ans=ans*10+2;
            scr.setText(ans);
        }
    });

thr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ans=ans*10+3;
    scr.setText(ans);
}
});

fou.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ans=ans*10+4;
    scr.setText(ans);
}
});

fiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ans=ans*10+5;
    scr.setText(ans);
}
});

six.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ans=ans*10+6;
    scr.setText(ans);
}
});

sev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ans=ans*10+7;
    scr.setText(ans);
}
});

eig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ans=ans*10+8;
    scr.setText(ans);
}
});

nin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ans=ans*10+9;
    scr.setText(ans);
}
});

zer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ans=ans*10;
    scr.setText(ans);
}
});


add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Ans();
    ca+=1;
    scr.setText("+");
}
});

sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Ans();
    cs+=1;
    scr.setText("-");
}
});

mul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Ans();
    cm+=1;
    scr.setText("*");
}
});

div.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Ans();
    cd+=1;
    scr.setText("/");
}
});

equ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Ans();
    scr.setText(fans);
}
});

clr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ans=0;
    fans=0;
    ca=0;cm=0;cd=0;cs=0;

    scr.setText("0");
}
});


}


public void Ans(){
if(ca>0)
{
    fans=fans+ans;
    ca=0;
}

else if(cs>0)
{
    fans=fans-ans;
    cs=0;
}

else if(cm>0)
{
    fans=fans*ans;
    cm=0;
}

else if(cd>0)
{
    fans=fans/ans;
    cd=0;
}
else
{
    fans=ans;
    ans=0;
}

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cal, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: What does "is not working" mean? Does your app crash? Are you getting an error message? Is the behaviour not according to your expectations? ... you need to be specific if you want your question to be answered. Dont let people guess.

Answer (score 1):

`scr` is textview and `ans` is a int. Your app probably crashes.

Replace this

```
  scr.setText(ans);
```

By

```
  scr.setText(String.ValueOf(ans));
```

`public static String valueOf(int i)`

> Returns the string representation of the int argument.

Same for all

`public final void setText (int resid)`

resid is a resource which is an int value.

`textView.setText(resid)` looks for a resid with that value. If it's not found you will get ResourceNotFoundException.

You should use the below

`public final void setText (CharSequence text)`

takes a CharSequence as a param

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)

There might me other mistakes also (which may lead to crash). If its a crash its better you post the stacktrace.